# SQL Query to Update Existing DateTime field and values in DB to PST from GMT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I am looking for the best way to write a query that takes an existing DateTime field/value in a database (there are over 50K rows) and updates the DateTime value to a different time zone. What I want to do is change the existing date/time value from GMT time (the current server time) to PST (would be minus 7 hours I think). I want to change the values in the database then I will change the server time on the server to PST to reflect the time zone so that all new records show the PST time zone.

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't do this at all.  Keep your data in GMT (really, UTC) in the database, and convert it to pacific time in your application logic as needed.  For example, if you connect to you SQL Server from a .NET application, query the UTC time from the database and convert it using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc`

The biggest reason for this is that Pacific time uses [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).  So while part of the year it follows PST (which is UTC-8), during the summer it follows PDT (which is UTC-7).  That means the amount of time to adjust by is *variable*, and depends on the date itself.

Not only that, but a value that occurs during the fall-back transition is *ambiguous* in local time.  For example, 2015-11-01 at 1:30 AM occurs *twice* in Pacific time.  If you convert all your data to Pacific time, you'll potentially lose some information.

If you *really* need to convert between time zones directly in SQL Server, consider using my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project.  For example:

```
SELECT Tzdb.UtcToLocal('2015-07-01 00:00:00', 'America/Los_Angeles')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have any built-in timezone conversion functionality. However, this can be accomplished via SQLCLR. You can create a scalar User-Defined Functions using the [DateTime.ToLocalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx) method.

Yes, technically you can use the [TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class which has methods such as `ConvertTime(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo, TimeZoneInfo)` and `ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)`, but the `TimeZoneInfo` class requires that the assembly have a `PERMISSION_SET` of `UNSAFE` whereas `DateTime` can run as `SAFE`. The only drawback to sticking with the `DateTime` methods is that they can only convert between UTC and the server's local time, as opposed to `TimeZoneInfo` which can convert between any two given time zones.

Since your data is already in GMT / UTC, it would be fairly easy to convert to Pacific* time using `DateTime.ToLocalTime`, *but* only if you change your server's time zone *before* updating the data, and not after (as is mentioned in the question). At which point you could do something like the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [SchemaName].[TableName]
  ADD [IsConverted] BIT NULL; -- make sure we don't convert multiple times

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
  UPDATE TOP (2000) tab
  SET    tab.DateField = dbo.ConvertTimeToLocalTime(tab.DateField),
         tab.IsConverted = 1
  FROM   [SchemaName].[TableName] tab
  WHERE  tab.IsConverted IS NULL;

  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN
    BREAK;
  END;
END;

-- Remove the temporary tracking field, but not until all rows are converted
IF (NOT EXISTS(
               SELECT *
               FROM   [SchemaName].[TableName] tab
               WHERE  tab.IsConverted IS NULL
              )
    )
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE [SchemaName].[TableName]
    DROP COLUMN [IsConverted];
END;
```

* **Please note** that I used "Pacific" time instead of PST because Pacific time can be either PST or PDT depending on Daylight Savings. Hence, trying to convert by simply doing `DATEADD(HOUR, -7, [DateField])` would be correct for some rows, but not all rows.

Also, for those interested in this particular conversion function, it is available (though not for free) in the Full version of the [SQL#](http://www.sqlsharp.com/) library (which I am the author of). There are some blog posts around that show how to do it, though I have not seen one that follows best practices such that it will perform optimally. Of course, if this is a one-time conversion, then optimal performance for a price is admittedly less important than less-efficient-but-free :-).

Answer (score -1):

You can change the database time zone by using the SET TIME_ZONE clause of the ALTER DATABASE statement. For example:

```
ALTER DATABASE SET TIME_ZONE='Europe/London';ALTER DATABASE SET TIME_ZONE='-05:00';
```

YOu can refer to the following link for further details. 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG263

Comment: I think you solution is more of a database time zone solution but it does not change existing date/time database values to the PST time zone from GMT.

Comment: @thenextmogul In addition to the point you made about it being a DB level setting, not the data itself, it is also an Oracle option, _not_ a SQL Server option.